# Amount of different numbers in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $[\frac{1^2}{2018}]$, $[\frac{2^2}{2018}]$, ...,$[\frac{2018^2}{2018}]$. ( $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$) How can I find the amount of different numbers in this sequence? The squares confuse me.

Comment: Evaluate the terms $1,2,3,45,90$ and you may get some inspiration.

Comment: Clearly, those are integers between $0$ and $2018$. You might want to try calculating how many integers from $0$ to $2018$ don't belong to this sequence. For that, maybe make use of how many numbers are between two next integer squares.

Answer (score 4):

If $(n+1)^2-n^2\ge 2018$ (equivalently, if $2n+1>2018$), then clearly
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{(n+1)^2}{2018}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{2018}\right\rfloor\ge 1.
$$
So, the numbers
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{2018}\right\rfloor, \quad n=1010,\ldots,2018
$$
are different from each other. In particular $\left\lfloor\frac{1010^2}{2018}\right\rfloor=505$

On the other hand,
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{2018}\right\rfloor, \quad n=1,\ldots,1009
$$
is a sequence, which is increasing but not strictly, and the diference of two consecutive terms can not exceed 1. Hence 
$$
\left\{\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{2018}\right\rfloor: n=1,\ldots,1009\right\}=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,\left\lfloor\frac{1009^2}{2018}\right\rfloor\right\}=\{0,1,\ldots,504\}
$$
Altogether:
$$
1009+505=1514
$$
different values.

Answer (score 0):

We have the sequence $(q_k)$ with
$$
q_k = \left \lfloor \frac{k^2}{2018} \right\rfloor \quad
(k \in I=\{ 1, \dotsc, 2018 \})
$$
The sequence starts with $q_1=0$ and finishes with $q_{2018} = 2018$.
It is monotonically increasing, but not strictly.

So how many different elements has $(q_k)$?

The difference between elements is
$$
\Delta q_k = q_{k+1} - q_k = \left \lfloor \frac{(k+1)^2}{2018} \right\rfloor -
\left \lfloor \frac{k^2}{2018} \right\rfloor
$$

We can write $\Delta q_k$ as
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta q_k 
&=
\frac{(k+1)^2}{2018} - \epsilon_1  -
\left( \frac{k^2}{2018} - \epsilon_2 \right) \\
&= 
\frac{2k+1}{2018} + \epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1 \\
&\in \left( \frac{2k+1}{2018}-1, \frac{2k+1}{2018}+1 \right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\epsilon_i \in [0,1)$ are the fractional parts.

Here is an image:

[image: graph]

The differences $\Delta q_k$ are rendered in red, they wobble around
the line $f(k) = (2k+1)/2018$, which is rendered in green. The bounds are parallel lines rendered in grey.

**Clashes:**

Elements are not different if $\Delta q_k = 0$, in this case the new value clashes with the last value.

There are no clashes, if our lower bound line is on or above the $x$-axis:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2k+1}{2018}-1 &\ge 0 \iff \\
k &\ge 1008.5
\end{align}
$$
Thus the feasible indices $1009$ to $2018$ will result in $1010$ distinct elements.

**Gaps:**

One index before, at $k=1008$, we have reached value
$$
q_{1008} 
= \left \lfloor \frac{1008^2}{2018} \right\rfloor 
= 503
$$
So this means there could be values from $0$ to $503$, which are $504$ different ones.

Is it possible, that less values showed up in the sequence up to this point?

This would be the case, if we had gaps, thus $\Delta q_k \ge 2$.

For gaps to be possible, our upper bound must be above the line $y = 2$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2k+1}{2018} + 1 &> 2 \iff \\
k &> 1008.5
\end{align}
$$
We are lucky, there is no gap possible for indices $1$ to $1008$, so all $504$ values have to show up in the sequence.

**Result:**

We have $504$ distinct sequence elements for indices $1$ to $1008$ and
$1010$ distinct sequence elements for indices $1009$ to $2018$.
This gives $1514$ distinct sequence elements in total.